# How to track the user message and user phone number to our application from twilio

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

I am working on handling inbound message of twilio. I have seen many of the link related to inbound message but i didn't know how to track the user message and user phone number.

Her are the links for the inbound messages of twilio
https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/09/an-easy-way-to-receive-an-sms-message-with-c-and-twilio.html
https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply-csharp

I want to know the response of the twilio whether they will the send the user message and user phone number.

Can somebody please help me and show/give some examples?

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When someone sends an SMS message to your Twilio number, Twilio will package the details about that message up as a POST request and send it your application URL.

The request is encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and you can parse the body of the request in order to get those details, including the `From` number, the `To` number and the `Body` of the request.

You can see more detail about this, and all the parameters, in the document on [Twilio's request to your application](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml#twilios-request-to-your-application).

Comment: Hi @Philnash,Thank you for the clarification. I have one more doubt, Twilio can generate and verify the otp by it's own or else generate the otp and send to the user . save the otp  which was sent and then verify the otp send by the user and saved otp.

Comment: You can do two factor authentication using Twilio’s Authy API. Check out the documentation here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy

Comment: ,The two factor authentication using Twilio’s Authy API is for login authentication. Can we use those Authy api for the sending otp and verify otp from our application through twilio.

Comment: The two factor authentication using the Authy API can be used for anything that you want to do 2FA for, not just login. I don't know what you mean when you say you want to verify the otp from your application through Twilio though. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I am working on, In our application i want to send the otp to user and verify the otp which was sent by the user. I want to do the whole operation of otp using twilio. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, that is all possible using Twilio's Authy API. Have you looked at the documentation? The API can be used to send the OTP and then when the user inputs the OTP on your site you can then verify it with the Authy API too.